# net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET from cloudfront pointed domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

We are getting `net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` from our static domain which is pointing to CloudFront.  We have faced this error randomly and not much frequently also we have checked aws health dashboard at that time all services working normally.

Comment: It looks like the internal office network issue. Haven't found root cause.